# Как тестируется web приложения?

Tags: веб-программирование, тестирование

Доброго времени суток.

Ребята может кто-то подскажет, как правильно тестировать web приложения? От начала до конца. А то мне попадало несколько вариантов, но очень отличаются друг от друга и толком ничего не ясно.

Answer (score 2):

1. Когда приложение построено по MVC принципу, то модель и контроллер тестируются стандартно: модульными тестами.
2. Сам сайт в целом тестируется вручную либо частично автоматически с помощью роботов на основе Selenium, Watin и т.п.